# A side pane file explorer that can list files by modification dates?

Tags: filesystem, plugin-nerdtree

I am looking for a way to be able to open a side pane listing the files in the current directories where the listing is sorted by modification dates. I want to be able to open the files from the listing as well.

I have the NERDTREE plugin, but I can't find a way to sort by dates. Perhaps I am missing some tricks?

Or is there some other plugin that can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the netrw plugin (which is included by default in recent versions), you can sort by date. Start netrw with the command `:Ex` (or `:Vex` to make it open as vertical split or "side pane" as you call it) then change the sorting order with <kbd>s</kbd>. You may also want to see the change dates. You can see this by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You could use netrw's :Lexplore command (usually shortened to :Lex) to get a side pane.  As Tumbler41 said, you can change the sorting order with `s`; you can also have netrw start up with that sorting method by putting `let g:netrw_sort_by= "time"` in your .vimrc.